# Questions about INET3.7

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm learning the code of 5G-Sim-V2I/N.
There are some problems in the file TrafficFlowFilterNR.cc: The author called IPv4Datagram.h in the header file. But 5G-Sim-V2I/N is done under SimuLTE and INET3.7. I am trying to run it in Simu5G and INET4.5. Called IPv4Datagram was renamed to IPv4Datagram a few years ago.

In TrafficFlowFilterNR.cc the author wrote:

**IPv4Datagram *datagram = check_and_cast<IPv4Datagram*>(msg);**

**datagram->removeControlInfo();**

**datagram->setControlInfo(tftInfo);**

The problem is that there are no functions removeControlInfo() and setControlInfo(tftInfo) in either IPv4Datagram or IPv4Datagram. I thought it might have something to do with Ipv4ControlInfo (which was removed a few years ago), but neither of these functions are in Ipv4ControlInfo either.
So I would like to ask for help: Can any developer experienced with INET 3.7 tell me where I can find these two functions? Thanks.

TrafficFlowFilterNR.cc: https://github.com/deinleinT/V2IV2Nsim/blob/master/5G-SIM-V2IN/lteNR/src/nr/epc/TrafficFlowFilterNR.cc

IPv4Datagram: https://github.com/deinleinT/V2IV2Nsim/blob/master/5G-SIM-V2IN/inet/src/inet/networklayer/ipv4/IPv4Datagram.cc

IPv4ControlInfo: https://github.com/deinleinT/V2IV2Nsim/blob/master/5G-SIM-V2IN/inet/src/inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4ControlInfo.cc